# Add string end column name dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have the following df:

```
                             BRET          CRET           NET
SEEN                          4             4              5       
NOT SEEN                      5             9              9          
DELETED                       9            14             13
```

I would like to add a string to each of the column headers.

The desired output would look like this:

```
                        BRET :this M      CRET : past M   NET : past 2 M
SEEN                          4             4              5       
NOT SEEN                      5             9              9          
DELETED                       9            14             13
```

The issue is that I would like not to rename the columns but simply add the strings at the end of the  column names

Would that be possible?

Comment: Is there a difference between "renaming the columns" and "adding strings at the end of the column names"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use .values:

```
df.columns.values[0] = df.columns.values[0] + ' :this M'
df.columns.values[1] = df.columns.values[1] + ' : past M'
df.columns.values[2] = df.columns.values[2] + ' : past 2 M'
```

Output:

```
          BRET: this M  CRET : past M  NET : past 2 M
SEEN                 4              4               5
NOT SEEN             5              9               9
DELETED              9             14              13
```